# Where is 'urinal' pronounced with a long 'i'?

Tags: pronunciation

The OED suggests both a short and a long 'i' are acceptable without assigning either to the UK or to the US:

- *ur **i** nal* — /ˈjʊər**ɪ**nəl/

and

- *ur **eye** nal* — /jʊəˈr**aɪ**nəl/

In my limited experience the only people who pronounce it with the long 'i' are from Great Britain. Conversely, I don't think I've ever heard an English person use the pronunciation with the short 'i'; my sample population is very small, however. Is this a regional-, age-, or class-dependent thing?

Comment: The second syllable is open, and open syllables in English usually have long vowels/diphthongs. Compare *decisive* → *de**sai**sive*.

Comment: This is dictionary stuff.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul: Short vowels can be in open unstressed syllables. Surely you don't pronounce *capital* like /ˈkapaɪtəl/ (CAP-eye-təl).

Comment: @PeterShor: Good catch!

Comment: I have suggested an edit to the question title to make it [less subjective](/help/dont-ask) and less likely to invite anecdotal answers. Given that this question has ended up on the Hot Network Questions list, I would like to remind visitors that the usual Stack Exchange guidelines on [how to write a good answer](/help/how-to-answer) apply here too — and, in particular, that good answers are generally expected to provide more than just personal anecdotes.

Comment: Gonna be honest, I forget what "long i" is supposed to mean. But fascinating, I've never heard of the latter pronuciation.

Answer (score 1):

The OED gives the pronunciation as both /jʊəˈrʌɪnəl/ and /ˈjʊərɪnəl/ without distinguishing between AE and BE.

I have a tendency towards:

As a noun: a place or vessel in which to urinate /jʊəˈrʌɪnəl/

"The gents' urinals are on the left."

As an adjective: relating to the urinary system, /ˈjʊərɪnəl/

"I am afraid you have a urinal infection."

Comment: Can you specify if you speak AmE or BrE (and are representative of it)?

Comment: I am a BE speaker originally from the East Midlands but also with decades spent in East Yorkshire and the South. I cannot say whether I am representative (I'm not sure what it means) but I have spoken it all my life.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's /jʊəˈr**aɪ**nəl/ rather than /jʊəˈr**ʌɪ**nəl/.

Comment: I'm asking about representative because a personal attestation is only about one person, but a representative one tells something about how many people do it. People are sometimes aware of their own regional accents or personal idiosyncrasies. Saying 'I have a tendency towards' means 'I am only talking about myself and this doesn't reflect on anybody else' (which is of little utility, and only worth a comment); 'In BrE people say' means that you think you have a good ear for what most people say (like what an editor at OED thinks).

Answer (score -1):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/urinal) gives regions for the pronunciations:

> (Received Pronunciation) ... IPA: `/juːˈɹaɪnəl/`
>
> (US) ... IPA: `/ˈjʊɹɪnəl/`, `/ˈjɝɪnəl/`
>
> (General Australian) ... IPA: `/ˈjʉːəɹɪnəl/`

I don't know where you're from, Marc, but [Received Pronunciation (RP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation) is "the Queen's English," and `/aɪ/` is the long-*i* sound you're asking about. It would rhyme with "final."

It looks like Forvo only has [recordings](https://forvo.com/search/urinal/en_usa/) for American English, because I was curious about how the Australian one would be pronounced, but it looks like it would rhyme with the American pronunciation, not the British one.

Although Wiktionary doesn't slavishly cite anything, it's regional pronunciations are usually fine, and this agrees with other answers on this page.

Comment: There are recordings of BE-RP, AE, and various other dialect pronunciations at https://www.wordreference.com/definition/urinal. However, there seems to be little rhyme or reason behind the pronunciations and I get the impression that another set of speakers would have given another set of answers.

Comment: @Greybeard Not being British, they seem fine to me. What would you say should be different?

Comment: The Australian pronunciation uses the British vowel for the *u* and the American vowel for the *i*, but all the vowels are pronounced with an Australian accent.

Comment: @PeterShor Well yes, i can see that, but i was having a hard time imagining it

Answer (score -2):

I, along with everyone I've ever heard say "urinal", pronounces it with an "ih" sound rather than an "eye" sound. I hope that helped!

Comment: It isn't helpful if you don't say what region you are from!

Comment: From UK, I only hear/say the 'eye' sound. I have been to US, but I never heard such words used openly, only euphemisms like "bath room" which boggles the imagination.

Comment: They pee in the bath?

Comment: Pretty much the same in the US.  "Your-eye-nul" would get strange looks.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - We pee in a urinal (rhymes with journal) which is located in the bathroom if it’s in a residence or in the restroom if it’s in a public space.  Although most bathrooms don’t have urinals just toilets.  :-)